# 'Undefined offset PHP' em um loop "for"

Tags: php

Estou tentando organizar umas pastas em ordem em uma aplicação que estou fazendo para FTP.
Segue o código que estou usando:

```
    if ($file->isDir()) {
                    echo '<table>';
                    $archive = [$file];
                    for($i = 0; $i <= $archive; $i++){
                        echo '<tr></tr>';
                        echo '<td><a href="index.php?path='.$dir. DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR .$archive[$i].'"><img src="icones/archive.ico" width="30px" height="30px"/></a></td>' . $file->getBaseName();
                    }       
                    echo '</table>';
                } else {
                    switch($file->getExtension()) {
  Restante do código...
```

Erro que aparece em tela:

```
Undefined offset: 1
```

Esse erro a cima cai em um loop infinito.

Comment: Estranho isto `$archive = [$file];`, qual a intenção? O que mostra um `var_dump($file);`?

Comment: $file é um objeto? Por que esta fazendo $archive = [$file]?

Comment: $file são as pastas do FTP que quero organizar.

Comment: `$i <= count($archive)`?

Answer (score 2):

O teu código actual apresenta uma série de problemas respeitantes ao uso das variáveis, matrizes, objectos e HTML. A sugestão para resolver cada um dos assuntos é extensa e carece o restante do código que utilizas até chegares ao excerto que consta da tua pergunta.

Alguns dos problemas visíveis na tua pergunta:

1. `$file` é um objecto, mas estás a passar o mesmo como chave da matriz `$archive`;
2. O teu ciclo `for()` só funcionaria com a implementação que tens, se a matriz `$archive` estivesse com chaves numéricas;
3. Estás a fazer output da `<tr></tr>` e só depois é que fazes output da `<td></td>`. As `TD` tem que estar dentro das `TR`.
4. Está a trabalhar a matriz `$archive` como se a mesma tivesse chaves numéricas que é o que a variável `$i` contém. (ver ponto 1);
5. Estás a concatenar `$file->getBaseName()` após fechares a `TD`. Teria que ficar concatenado antes da `TD` ser fechada;
6. Se não existirem resultados, vais ter uma tabela sem conteúdos;

---

## Listar Ficheiros e Directorias

Pelo que entendi, pretendes listar ficheiros e directorias de determinado caminho para apresentar ao utilizador. Em baixo segue um exemplo a funcionar que ilustra isso mesmo:

```
<?php

$outputHtml = '';

$pathToList = dirname(__FILE__);            // caminho a listar
$dir = new DirectoryIterator($pathToList);  // Iterar o caminho

// por cada entrada encontrada
foreach ($dir as $fileinfo) {

  // se não for "." ou ".."
  if (!$fileinfo->isDot()) {

    /* Verificar se é directoria ou ficheiro
     * para definir o icon a utilizar
     */
    if ($fileinfo->isDir()) {
      $icon = 'https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/snipicons/5000/folder-close-32.png';
    }
    else {
      $icon = 'https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/snipicons/500/file-32.png';
    }

    /* actualizar a variável de output com o HTML
     * referente a este ficheiro/directoria
     */    
    $outputHtml.= '
    <div>
      <a href="index.php?path='.$fileinfo->getPathname().'">
        <img src="'.$icon.'" width="32px" height="32px"/> '.$fileinfo->getFilename().'
      </a>
    </div>';
  }
}

/* Apresentar a listagem ou se não temos
 * resultados apresentar uma mensagem.
 */
if (!empty($outputHtml)) {
  echo $outputHtml;
}
else {
  echo '<p>Não foram encontrados ficheiros ou directorias para o caminho indicado!</p>';
}

?>
```

O código em cima vai-te dar uma listagem semelhante à captura de tela em baixo apresentada:

[image: Exemplo da Listagem]

Resumidamente, o que está a ser feito é:

1. Definir o caminho a listar na variável `$pathToList`:

   ```
   $pathToList = "/caminho/para/destino/*";
   ```
2. Fazendo uso do método **[`DirectoryIterator`](http://is.php.net/manual/en/directoryiterator.construct.php)** <sup>(Inglês)</sup> construímos uma iteração da directoria:

   ```
   $dir = new DirectoryIterator($pathToList);
   ```
3. Por cada entrada localizada, realizamos as acções pretendidas. No exemplo em cima estamos a listar o conteúdo localizado atribuindo um icon para quando é ficheiro e um outro icon para quando é uma directoria.

   ```
   foreach ($dir as $fileinfo) {
     ...
   }
   ```
4. Apresentamos o resultado ao utilizador caso tenhamos encontrado algo, se não, apresentamos uma mensagem.

Answer (score 1):

Você tem um `array` no seu [`for`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php) – isso não vai funcionar. Tente isso:

```
for($i = 0; $i <= $file; $i++) {
    // o seu código aqui
}
```

Se ainda não for, vamos pensar: você tem uma condição `$file->isDir()`, o que significa que `$file` não possui mais de um valor – é pra ser um objeto – e você está o *vetorizando*, o que **não faz sentido**.

Em palavras mais técnicas, você está convertendo um objeto singular para um vetor, e para o `for` isso é inútil e não vai funcionar.